# Acrostic Poem - Programming

Tags: popularity-contest

TASK:

Make an acrostic poem in the lines.
e.g.

BATCH

```
break  
attrib -h acrostic.txt  
type acrostic.txt  
cls  
help
```

The output CAN also be an acrostic poem.

RULES:

- Popularity Contest - the answer with highest vote wins!
- You may create more than one.
- Any language is accepted.
- Every line must be executable.

Comment: Your question might be a good one, but it is poorly written now. Please, try to improve it.

Comment: Imho it is a bit broad as it is currently written.

Comment: how are to be considered the ubiquitous $ in PHP?

Comment: Sorry, for special characters you can decide. $ you can read it as dollar or just not read it. Other reading will be accepted.

Comment: Please include <how to read>. It will be easier for reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java**

```
class s {
//acrostic starts below this line  
public static void main(String[] args) { int
a; int
n;
class b {}
a=1; int 
k; int
e;
System.out.println("are very tasteful."); } }
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash - every man dies alone

This line writes the poem:

```
echo echo view echo renice yes make apropos nice date identify echo start apropos locate octave nice echo | xargs -n 1 | awk '{s = s substr($1, 1, 1); if ($1 == "echo"){print $1, "-n", s; s = "";}else print $1, "--they >.said 2>&1";}' > acrostic.sh
```

To see the poem:

```
$ cat acrostic.sh
```

To see the poem within the poem:

```
$ sh acrostic.sh
```

Comment: @Jamie, It's Bash.

Comment: @Jamie, don't worry... it's a matter of time. Just don't try to tackle GolfScript or APL in too much of a hurry!

Answer (score 1):

### Batch

Quite lazy, I'll admit -

```
@(
Code
Other than that which
Does
Echo Code^
Golf
Often
Lacks the
Fun
) 2>nul
```

```
H:\uprof>accro.bat
CodeGolf
```

Comment: I'm frozen - "code" "other than that which" "does" "often" "lacks the" "fun" are all invalid programs.

Comment: This is invalid. All lines must be executable. I can write a better with 2>nul.

Comment: Changing the rules - uncool.

Comment: Yes, that's uncool and quite rude - but to prevent these invalid acrostic poem, i guess i need to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Yay! **Java**!

```
import java.io.*;public
class poem{static String[]
a = 
new String[1];
public static void main(String[] args){a();fin();
return;}static
Object myMethod(){String
g = "This is my ";
return g;} static void a(){
a[0] = "output";}static boolean fin(){System.out.println(
myMethod().toString()+a[0]);Boolean fin =
!(0==1);return fin;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93

```
go down, "Dev" 00ps -- 2*4-10 \ please
um I guess 1 - 3 \, is that right "hmm", @
maybe
```

run as `./befungee.py acrostic` for the output `gum`.

Note sure how rule #3 should be interpreted in this context.

Comment: Not sure if this is better suited at [link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/write-a-short-story-using-only-valid-code). Would be stretching the definition of a story a bit though...

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby**

```
ruby = "rubylicious"; control = true
unless (!ruby)
begin y = ruby
y.each_char do |l| print (
l)
if (l=='s') then 
control=false end  
if (!control) then puts "!" end
over = true
unless 
self == true then over = false end end end end
```

This prints `Rubylicious!`. I am not happy with some of the lines (especially last line), so future edits are possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
document.getElementById("dog).appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
o = [];
e = [];
s = [];

t = 0;
h = 0;
i = 0;
s[0] = 0;

e[0] = 0;
v = 0;
e[1] = 0;
n = [];

c = 0;
o[0] = 0;
u = 0;
n[0] = 0;
t
? count=1:count=0;
```